# Submitting form to couchDB through update handler not working

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I can not post to CouchDB through an update handler and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Below follows the long description.

I created an app using erica, with details taken primarily from the wiki. It worked fine until I decided to go for POSTing, but server-side, through an update handler according to [Apache CouchDB wiki Working_with_Forms](http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/couchdb_tasklist/index.html)

I created a new 'webapp' with erica, constructed an index (cut-n-paste from the wiki, with small alterations):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Minimal Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="contact-form">
  <form id="contact" method="post" action="/mydatabase/_design/mydesigndoc/_update/postForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Enter your name" class="required">

        <label for="phone">phone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="+1 (555) 555-5555" required="" pattern="\+?[0-9 )(-]+">

        <label for="email">e-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@example.org" title="e-mail address" class="required email">

        <label for="blog">blog</label>
        <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="http://">

        <label for="message">message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

I altered the form-attribute `action=` to: `htttp://localhost:5984/DBNAME/_design/DESIGNDOCID/_update/UPDATENAME` and added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Then a `_design` document was constructed, according to the wiki, like this:

```
{
updates: {
    postForm: function(previous, request) {

        /* during development and testing you can write data to couch.log
    log({"previous": previous})
    log({"request": request})
    */
    var doc = {}
    if (!previous) {
            // there's no existing document _id as we are not using PUT
            // let's use the email address as the _id instead
            if (request.form && request.form.email) {
                // Extract the JSON-parsed form from the request
                // and add in the user's email as docid
                doc = request.form
                doc._id = request.form.email
            }
        }
        return [doc, toJSON({
            "request": request,
            "previous": previous,
            "doc": doc
        })]
    }
}
}
```

This was placed in the "ddoc"-folder, pushed the app with erica, opened the webpage according to the link, found the form but when it was submitted this is what answer I got:

```
{"error":"unnamed_error","reason":"(new TypeError(\"point is undefined\", \"/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js\", 1475))"}
```

I have fiddled around with the action="..." attribute, even put absolute adress like this:

```
http://localhost:5984/mydatabase...
```

I have replaced the toJSON() with JSON.stringify().

I have restarted the process and done the project it all over again. To no avail.

I have the distinct feeling that I have gone "blind", and that the solution is probably just in front of my eyes but I cannot see it. Seems like there is no problem with the POST-http-request, cause the server has complained before when I have experimented with AJAX (forgot "content-type"), but this time it seems to be internal server problems. And I do not have a clue. Really.

All in all, the question is: Can somebody help me? Please.

Comment: I know it is a long description. As I have read various posts on this site the most common comment I find is that the question/description is vague and/or needs to be elaborated. So I did.
Is it too long/elaborated? Should I cut down on it to get an answer?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but since you asked: Yes. PLEASE, cut down on the description. Include only relevant details.  I have done some editing for you.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question and at the same time ask forgiveness from those who wasted their time with it.

What I did is that I read through [kanso](http://kan.so/) and understood how the concept of scope applies to the situation. It is a matter of using `exports` on the update handler so it can be reached through `<form action="/database/_design/designDocument/_update/updateFunction`.

Why did I not read through Kan.so earlier? Well, I had my mind set on keeping it simple - `erica` being the successor of `couchapp` I decided that it would be a sound move to stay on course with the basics. Though I must say that documentation is scarce so the magic of couchapp-building was demystified by reading through Kan.so and on top of it I was introduced to several other nifty concepts and techniques. I bend my neck in gratitude.

And I hope that all those who have spent their time reading through my long and, as it turned out, unnecessary question will oversee with my  ignorance.

(Now I only wonder if there is some kind of admin/moderator who can dispose of my writings to avoid future timel oss)

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran into the same problem, and your answer will help me find how to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this error and what causes it, as hinted at by @Pea-pod, is not defining properly your `exports` in the couchapp's design documents. In our case it was as list function that couldn't be called and instead displayed a 500 error with `Type error` and `point is undefined` in the couchdb log.

We use [kanso](http://kan.so/) and in the app.js we hadn't required the list file. We had:

```
module.exports = {
    rewrites: require('./rewrites'),
    views: require('./views'),
    shows: require('./shows')
};
```

Changing it to the following solved the problem:

```
module.exports = {
    rewrites: require('./rewrites'),
    views: require('./views'),
    shows: require('./shows'),
    lists: require('./lists')
};
```

Can I suggest to a moderator to change the title of this question to include `point is undefined` which is the error that shows up in the CouchDB log when this type of error is made, in order to help others find it more easily?