# CouchDB list function throwing TypeError (point is undefined)

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am attempting to get a list out of my database. The documents look like:

```
{
"class": "lists",
"collection": "symptoms",
"order": "6",
"en": "Headache",
"_id": "9022034e7d5ecd0efab0762c5b7f0c04"
}
```

There are an arbitrary number of "collection"s.

A view function simply returns a bunch of objects in the class "lists":

```
// Emit lists
exports.viewlist = {
  map: function(doc) {
    if (doc.class === 'lists') {
        emit(
            doc.collection, {
                order: doc.order,
                name: doc.en
            });
    }
  }
};
```

I wrote a list function to try to filter the output to just the list that I want.

```
exports.viewlist = function(head, req) {
  var row;
  start({
    code: 200,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json; charset=utf-8',
  }
});
while (row = getRow()) {
    if (row.collection === req.l) {
      send(JSON.stringify(row.value));
    }
  }
};
```

CouchDB throws an error when I visit the URL of the list:

```
http://localhost:5984/dev/_design/emr/_list/viewlists/viewlist?l=symptoms

{"error":"TypeError","reason":"{[{<<\"message\">>,<<\"point is undefined\">>},     
{<<\"fileName\">>,<<\"/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js\">>},  
{<<\"lineNumber\">>,1500},\n  {<<\"stack\">>,
<<\"(\\\"_design/emr\\\",[object Array],
[object Array])@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1500\
()@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1562\
@/usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1573\
\">>}]}"}
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: This question has just been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21362699/3237351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this error and what causes it, as hinted at by @Pea-pod here [Submitting form to couchDB through update handler not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17908321/3237351), is not defining properly your `exports` in the couchapp's design documents. In our case it was as list function that couldn't be called and instead displayed a 500 error with `Type error` and `point is undefined` in the couchdb log.

We use kanso and in the app.js we hadn't required the list file. We had:

```
module.exports = {
    rewrites: require('./rewrites'),
    views: require('./views'),
    shows: require('./shows')
};
```

Changing it to the following solved the problem:

```
module.exports = {
    rewrites: require('./rewrites'),
    views: require('./views'),
    shows: require('./shows')
    lists: require('./lists'),
};
```

Can I suggest to a moderator to change the title of this question to include `point is undefined` which is the error that shows up in the CouchDB log when this type of error is made, in order to help others find it more easily?